# Total number of SOQL queries issued

Tags: governorlimits, limits

> In a SOQL query with parent-child relationship sub-queries, each
>   parent-child relationship counts as an additional query. These types
>   of queries have a limit of three times the number for top-level
>   queries.
>   [Understanding Execution Governors and Limits](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm)

but when I run the query like

```
[select id, (select id from childs__r) from parent]
```

it is printed that: Number of SOQL queries: 1 out of 100

but based on the previous statement it should be 2

And what the statement means:

> These types
>   of queries have a limit of three times the number for top-level
>   queries

Answer (score 3):

If you look at a Test Runner, you'll see different types of SOQL query reports, not just lines returned. I always see something that looks like this:

```
07:31:09.985|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
Number of SOQL queries: 22 out of 100
Number of query rows: 76 out of 50000

07:31:09.985|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|mea|
Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000

07:31:09.985|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|rh2|
Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000

07:31:09.985|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|rhx|
Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
```

I have similar "related" subqueries and always see them reported as "Aggregations" not as parent-child queries as in the example below:

```
07:31:31.501 (45501966062)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[50]|Aggregations:3|select Id,
Ambassador_Rate__c, Additional_Paid_Time__c, EventID__c, RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name,
Owner.Id, Program_PO__c, SWS_Recomended_CE__r.Id, Automation_Errors__c, (select Id,
ActivityDateTime, Actual_Hours__c, WhoID, WhatId, OwnerID, RecordTypeId from Events),
(select Id, Opportunity__c from R00N40000001pm1JEAQ), (select Id, PromoEvent__c from
Recap_Forms_New__r) from Opportunity where (Id = :tmpVar1 and
(Opportunity.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Setup_PromoEvent' or
Opportunity.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Approved_PromoEvent'))
```

In many cases, something may be a "related" to another object, making it act as "child". I suspect the documentation is referring to a parent-child relationship where one is the Master and the other the Detail; not the situation where one object is the related object of another and thus behaves as a child but is not the child in a Master-Detail relationship.

**Edit**

The point I'm trying to make is that many *related* relationships can be unclear and it appears to me that SF is reporting them all as `Aggregations` regardless of whether they're the *direct child of a parent* or simply on a *related object*. In the example above, `Events` is obviously a *related object*, but not a *direct child* of `Opportunity`. The same applies to `Recap_Forms_New__r`. However, `Opportunity` is the *parent* of `R00N40000001pm1JEAQ`, yet all 3 are shown as `Aggregations`. When I study what's reported as the log progresses, only the *query rows* increase because of the `Aggregations`, not the number of *SOQL queries.*